# Detect when Path2D with SVG path string is supported

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, html5-canvas, microsoft-edge

It appears Microsoft Edge partially supports the [Path2D API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D) - it doesn't support the usage SVG path strings, i.e.,

```
const path = new Path2D('M20 L30');
```

Is there a way to feature detect whether or not passing in SVG paths is supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *catchable* error that gets thrown in this case, and passing an invalid string does not throw either in supporting browsers. <sup><sub>(This sounds like a specs flow to me btw...)</sub></sup>

So to be able to detect this exact case of the constructor being supported, but the argument getting ignored, we have to actually check if something got drawn or not...

You can do so by stroking a simple `M0,0H1` Path2D and then check if the pixel at coords *0,0* of you context has been painted.

```js
function supports() {
  // no simple support
  if (typeof Path2D !== 'function') return false;
  // create a new context
  var x = document.createElement('canvas')
    .getContext('2d');
  // stroke a simple path
  x.stroke(new Path2D('M0,0H1'));
  // check it did paint something
  return !!x.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data[3];
};

console.log(supports());
```

But note that Edge does not seem to support either the [*Path2D.addPath()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/addPath) method, so if you include a polyfill like Google's [canvas-5-polyfill](https://github.com/google/canvas-5-polyfill) which does include a Path2D polyfill, then the whole Path2D will use the polyfilled version (because they also check for *addPath* support).